# How to make an tunnel between reverse proxy nginx and server?

Tags: nginx, ipv6, tunnel

I am preparing ipv6 of my webserver for ios app. Now I've my server build on a vps that not support ipv6. So I set up a reverse proxy nginx on another server that support ipv6. I want to make the reverse proxy listen on only ipv6, then forward to the server by the tunnel. How to setup the tunnel?

Comment: It'd probably be easier to move to a hosting environment that support IP6.

Comment: @Tim For some reasons, its not proper to migrate to an ip6 environment. For most ISP not support ipv6 in our country, and the there is so much data in the present vps.

Comment: Most ISPs are foolish, and will remain so until taught their error by their customers leaving.

Comment: You could put CloudFlare in front of your server. It can accept IP4 or IP6 requests, and send them to your server as IP4. It might take some fiddling to get it right. Otherwise you probably need a VPN tunnel, for which you'd google "how to create a VPN tunnel".

Comment: @Tim I can create tunnel when the server and proxy both with ipv4. But now this simple tunnel not works when the proxy listen on ipv6. Or is there something I have to config.

Comment: Although I appreciate people migrating their networks to IPv6 ... You do know that your server does _not_ have to offer IPv6 (yet) for your IOS app to pass the Appstore tests on IPv6? It's just that an IOS _client_ must work in an IPv6-only network (where IPv4-only hosts are still reachable using [NAT64/DNS64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_transition_mechanism#NAT64). If your app fails this test, there is a problem with the app, e.g. you are addressing the server by IP address instead of by name.

Comment: @Dubu It's my first develop ios app, I need to carefully read the app store review guidelines to check it.